# What is this declaration and what's its use?

Tags: c, linux

In `signal.h` there is declaration of `signal` function:

```
void (*signal(int signo, void (*func)(int))) (int);
```

How to interpret this and what's the use of declaring in this weird way?

Comment: People, don't upvote this. Dupe hundreds of times. Just becuase you don't understand it, it doesn't mean it's a great question. In fact, it isn't.

Comment: @H2CO3 - except that if you paste that into cdecl.org it claims it's a syntax error, even though it isn't.

Comment: @detly Then you paste it with argument names taken out, and it will happily recognize it.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Okay, but a beginner wouldn't necessarily know to do that. I didn't. And cdecl is still just plain wrong, because it's not a syntax error. I'm not disputing that this is an FAQ, but cdecl is a useless thing to post here unless you're going to explain how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `signal` function takes an `int` and a function pointer as arguments, and returns a function pointer. The function pointer argument and the returned function pointer each take an `int` argument, and returns `void`.

The `signal` prototype is sometimes written this way:

```
typedef void (*signal_handler_type) (int);

signal_handler_type signal (int, signal_handler_type);
```

Since the `signal` function allows the caller to replace the existing signal handler, it returns the one that was replaced after the call.

Answer (score 1):

on APUE,

> The prototype for the signal function states that the function
>   requires two arguments and returns a pointer to a function that
>   returns nothing (void ). The signal function's first argument, signo ,
>   is an integer. The second argument is a pointer to a function that
>   takes a single integer argument and returns nothing. The function
>   whose address is returned as the value of signal takes a single
>   integer argument (the final (int) ). In plain English, this
>   declaration says that the signal handler is passed a single integer
>   argument (the signal number) and that it returns nothing. When we call
>   signal to establish the signal handler, the second argument is a
>   pointer to the function. The return value from signal is the pointer
>   to the previous signal handler.

The perplexing signal function prototype shown  can be made
much simpler through the use of the following typedef:

```
typedef void Sigfunc(int);
```

Then the prototype becomes

```
Sigfunc *signal(int, Sigfunc *)
```

Comment: Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment.

Answer (score 0):

`Signal` function specifies a way to handle the signals with the signal number specified by signo(here).

Parameter `func` specifies one of the three ways in which a signal can be handled by a program:
 you can look 
[here][1]

[1]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/ for more details